# How can I pull a list of starred (favorite) locations from Google maps API?

Tags: google-maps

I've looked into the Maps, Places and G+ APIs but there's no info on retrieving a user's list of starred locations. Is there a way retrieve the info?

An example of the starred locations in Google Maps https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTeo0.png

Comment: this answer can help you http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16177/is-there-a-way-to-export-my-starred-locations-from-google-maps